# Firestore Collection on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add two new fields Mobile and Message for an existing userid, the user id is not null id is printing on the Log, but when I try to push the value, the app crashes and gives me the following error.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference*

What am I doing wrong?

```
userphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
usermessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_message);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String phone = userphone.getText().toString().trim();
                final String message = usermessage.getText().toString().trim();


                    String userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);

                    Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();

                    user.put("user_phone",userphone.getText().toString().trim());
                    user.put("user_message", usermessage.getText().toString().trim());

                    documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boooo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fStore` is null.  You probably never gave it a value, but we can't see where you defined it.  You're going to have to assign it `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I was not using getInstance(), also now I'm facing another issue. when I push the value it's updated on the user fields, but the previous fields get deleted.

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the values ; instead you're replacing the prevoius map with a new one. Use fstore.collection().document().update(key,value,key,value); to update specific fields without modifying other values.